# android how to collections.sort the object?

Tags: java, object

Now I have 3object

```
user[0] = new user("a", "a");
user[1] = new user("b", "b");
user[2] = new user("c", "c");
```

there have many variable in the object such as:
age, name, email

then the program is running.....

```
user[0].setAge(6);
user[1].setAge(5);
user[2].setAge(7);
```

how can I get the young to old user name?

the exception return:
b,a,c

Comment: Create comparator which will use result of `getAge` and pass it to `Collections.sort` along with your collection of `user`.

Comment: Or you can implement any of the sort methods existing

Comment: Use standard naming conventions, and certainly never create a variable with the same name as a class!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either make `User` [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) and have it's natural ordering by age:

```
public class User implements Comparable<User> {
    // snipped...

    @Override
    public int compareTo (User other) {
        return Integer.compare(age, other.age);
    }
}
```

Or explicitly specify a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) when you're sorting:

```
Collections.sort(users, new Comparator<User>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(User a, User b) {
        return Integer.compare(a.getAge(), b.getAge());
    }
});
```